# Git - Updated the remote URL, but not changing old URLs?

Tags: git

I'm attempting to update the remote url for my repo using:

```
git remote set-url origin https://newserver/root/repo.git
```

The expected result should be:

```
git remote -v
origin  http://newserver/root/repo.git (fetch)
origin  http://newserver/root/repo.git (push)
```

however regardless of what I try, and what articles I look at online, what I actually get as a result is something like this:

```
git remote -v
origin  http://oldserver/root/repo.git (fetch)
origin  http://oldserver/root/repo.git (push)
origin  http://newserver/root/repo.git (push)
```

When I try to use

```
git remote rm origin
```

It removes the new/third entry, yet leaves the other original entries for some reason. So I see:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote -v
origin  http://oldserver/root/repo.git (fetch)
origin  http://oldserver/root/repo.git (push)
```

After this, if I open the .git/config in vi, there's no entries at all. Manually adding the new server as origin in the config file yields the same result - I see the two old servers as fetch and push, and a third new entry which is also listed as origin/push.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried searching high and low, yet because of the terminology I'm not sure if I'm searching for the right information. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your git version, please? And can you reproduce this behavior in another repository?

Comment: `git config -e` to edit the local config file. There may be two remote "origin" urls. Remove the unwanted one.

Comment: I'm running git 2.5.0. When I look into the config file, there's only one listed origin url which is why I find this so strange

Comment: @YoannFleuryDev I have also noticed this behaviour in another repository that uses the same server for origin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appeared to be caused by a conflicting .git/config file... User error.

Answer (score 2):

Try an another way:

```
git config remote.origin.url https://newserver/root/repo.git
```

You used HTTPS, you maybe try use SSH, for example

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Learn more: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh

Comment: It's still just setting the third 'origin' as the git@ ssh address, but not forgetting/overwriting the original two - same behaviour as before :-/